# Issues with Stripe Payments for Event bookings

Tags: stripe

I have an event setup in  civiCRM with payments via stripe where one person so far has had issues booking in  and then the payment has not gone through and gives no conformation etc to them. No details are found within Civi apart from the following in teh log files

> 113   Dec 17 18:20:05     [error] Stripe.process_stripe: Unable to cancel
> paymentIntentID: 142: No such payment_intent:
> 'seti_1MG31RKqyqAxy8JVpUAMvMIp'
> 111    Dec 17 16:19:11     [error] Stripe
> Payment Error: Property 'paymentIntentID' has not been set.

This person is booking in multiple people and has previously booked into events so details are already in Civi
Thoughts please?

Comment: Not sure what version you are on but this one was previously logged and resolved https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/stripe/-/issues/387 and may be worth looking at in your case as it may well be the same issue.

Comment: Doh should have listed  version numbers On  CiviCRM 5.55.2 running on Wordpress 6.1.1 Stripe extension 6.7.14  I had looked at that, so not the same issue

Comment: It is also posting in the logs Attempted to create paymentIntent from paymentMethod during doPayment failed: stdClass Object. It appears to be happening with people who are repat customers?